# How can I build a Perl distribution with DIst::Zilla and use Carton for dependencies?

Tags: perl, dist-zilla

I have a perl distribution I have built with [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/release/Dist-Zilla), and so I do not have to contaminate my installed Perl's lib with the dependencies, I have used [Carton](https://metacpan.org/release/Carton) to manage them.

Things work great in development, but when I run `dzil test` or `dzil release` and tests are run, then the dependencies are not found and tests fail because the modules cannot be loaded.

I have tried `carton exec -- dzil test` and `PERL5LIB=local/lib/perl5 dzil test` but I think that means i need to put all my Dist::Zilla deps into the cpanfile, which seems plain wrong (I do have Dist::Zilla and the deps I need installed in my perl's lib path).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with:

```
export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/absolute/path/to/project/local/lib/perl5; dzil release
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we need to do if we want to separate the dependencies between the develop and the package itself and install everything via carton (that is, do not keep them in the system). And at the same time when Dist::Zilla::Plugin::CPANFile overwrite package cpanfile.

1. install all Dist::Zilla and other development dependencies on a separate path using carton via cpanfile
2. link these local libs to main project
3. here you do something in your project, for example, add more dependencies
4. `carton exec dzil build` (Dist::Zilla::Plugin::CPANFile will automagically create cpanfile with projects dependencies)
5. install them as usual with `carton`
6. from now on `carton exec dzil test` will work!

Let me illustrate this as if all development dependencies are in the dev directory:

```
#!perl

chdir 'dev'; 
system 'carton'; # (1)
chdir ".."; # (2)
if (!-l "local") { symlink("dev/local", "local") or die $@; } # (2)
if (!-l "cpanfile.snapshot") { symlink("dev/cpanfile.snapshot", "cpanfile.snapshot") or die $@; } # (2)
system 'carton'; # (5)

print "done\n";
```